# Como conectar ao MongoDB Compass Community?

Tags: mongodb

Eu instalei o mongodb na minha maquina e junto com ele veio o programa Compass Community.

Quando executei o mongod.exe pode perceber o nome do host e o a porta, então eu coloquei o nome do host no campo Hostname, e a posta na campo Port no Compass Community, porém mesmo assim não conecto e deu a mensagem dizendo **MongoDB not running on the provided host and port**

Saberiam me explicar como conectar o Compass Community no mongodb?

Comment: Está instalando em Windows? se sim, configurou o Path?

Comment: estou usando o windows, não configurei o Path

Comment: como faço para configurar o path? o caminho do executavel é esse 
C:\Users\wladi\AppData\Local\MongoDBCompassCommunity\MongoDBCompassCommunity.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiramente, acho que é importante ressaltar que tudo o que você precisar saber sobre mongoDB de inicio, vai encontrar facilmente na [documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/). Para conseguir conectar no Compass você precisa ter uma instância do MonGOD rodando e colocar IP e Porta corretamente nos campos antes de conectar-se. Também é necessário configurar o File Path, segue os passos:

1- Vá a pasta de instalação do Mongo e encontre a pasta **Bin**.

2- Copie o caminho até a pasta.

3- No menu iniciar, procure por **"variáveis de ambiente"**.

4- Na aba **"Avançado"**, no canto inferior direito, clique em **"Variáveis do Ambiente".**

5- É para ter uma variável com o nome de **"Path"**, edite o valor dela com o caminho da pasta Bin, copiado anteriormente.

Espero ter ajudado.